# How can I add my swing component into an open source Enterprise Application

Tags: java, swing, web, ejb, enterprise

I am working on customization of product which is web based enterprise application. I wanted to add a swing frame into an EJB class. I tried adding it directly into the EJB class, but on deployment it is throwing `javax.ejb.EJBException` . Is there any way so that I can add my swing component? please help me.

```
  public void logIn() throws ServletException, AccountNotFoundException, IOException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest());     
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) request.getSession();



        request.login(login, password);

        Account account = userManager.getAccount(login);

        JFrame fr= new JFrame();

        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(fr, "hi");

        fr.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        fr.setVisible(true);

.
.
.
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to connect to some EJB from a client-swing-desktop application? Because swing applications don't make sense in server environment.

Comment: As far as I know it isnt possible,could try writing the code for swings in java,then make it into a jnlp file.And then call it from the web based application.I did the same thing when I was on a JSP project.Give it a try and let us know.